# String class == operator not working properly

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am trying to compare my the data in my string buffer variable to string literals in an if-statement. For some reason, it works for the first case but not the second or third even though the input file has the proper format(no spaces either). What could the problem be?

```
while(getline(input, check)) //calculates size of sections array and rooms array
    {
        count++;
        cout<<check<<endl;
        if(check == "-- building room_number capacity")
        {
            Section1 = true;
            pos[0] = count;

            if(pos[0] != 1)
                return 0;
        }
        else if (check == "-- ID prefix course# sect# #minutes #mtgsperweek #students")
        {
            Section1 = false;
            Section2 = true;
            pos[1] = count;

            if(blanks > 1 || blanksPos != pos[1] - 1)
                return 0;
            else
                blanks = 0;
        }
        else if (check == "-- ID days_constraint start_contraint end_constraint")
        {
            Section2 = false;
            Section3 = true;
            pos[2] = count;

            if(blanks > 1 || blanksPos != pos[2] - 1)
                return 0;
            else
                blanks = 0;
        }
        else if (Section1 && check != "-- building room_number capacity")
        {
            if(check.size() == 0)
            {
                blanks++;
                blanksPos =count; 
            }
            else
                roomsize++;
        }
        else if (Section2 && check != "-- ID prefix course# sect# #minutes #mtgsperweek #students")
        {
            if(check.size() == 0)
            {
                blanks++;
                blanksPos =count; 
            }
            else
                sectionsize++;
        }
        else if (Section3 && check != "-- ID days_constraint start_contraint end_constraint")
        {
            if(check.size() == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
                constraintsize++;
        }   
        cout<<"R:" << roomsize << " S:" << sectionsize << " C:" << constraintsize << " blanks :" << blanks<<endl ;
    }
```

Some output:
Welcome to the classroom assignment program!
Enter the input file: input.txt

```
-- building room_number capacity
R:0 S:0 C:0 blanks :0
SAL 210 30
R:1 S:0 C:0 blanks :0
OHE 100 120
R:2 S:0 C:0 blanks :0
OHE 120 50
R:3 S:0 C:0 blanks :0

R:3 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
-- ID pre course# sect# #minutes #meetingsperweek #students
R:4 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20001 CSCI 101 01 110 2 40
R:5 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20002 CSCI 101 02 110 2 60
R:6 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20003 CSCI 101 03 110 2 100
R:7 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20004 CSCI 103 01 90 2 50
R:8 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20005 CSCI 103 02 90 2 50
R:9 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20006 CSCI 103 03 90 2 75
R:10 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20007 CSCI 104 01 80 2 50
R:11 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20008 CSCI 104 02 80 2 50
R:12 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20009 CSCI 109 01 90 1 25
R:13 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20010 CSCI 109 02 90 1 25
R:14 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20011 CSCI 109 03 90 1 25
R:15 S:0 C:0 blanks :1
20012 CSCI 109 04 90 1 25
R:16 S:0 C:0 blanks :1

R:16 S:0 C:0 blanks :2
-- ID days_constraint start_contraint end_constraint
```

As you can see, it's not detecting "-- ID pre course# sect# #minutes #meetingsperweek #students" even though check outputs the same thing as the test case. Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is that C++ doesn't know that `mtgs` is short for `meetings`

Comment: Show the declaration of `check`.

Comment: Also, your third `if` statement has `contraint` in a place where `constraint` would have been more likely. This is why long complicated strings are not good choices for section markers.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out in the comments and the previous answers, **you have spelled some of the text in the code incorrectly.** While comparing strings it is important to give an exact match otherwise it will return false (or 0).

You need to carefully compare only that which has been written in your file.

For example:

File contents:

```
"-- ID pre course# sect# #minutes #meetingsperweek #students"
```

Code compares:

```
"-- ID prefix course# sect# #minutes #mtgsperweek #students"
```

Both these strings are different and hence comparing them will return false (or 0).

A simple measure to avoid such errors is (as has already been suggested) to copy-paste the exact string from the file while comparing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the line from the text file so you don't *mispell* the words.